# qt creator still use the origin project after I move the project to another place

Tags: c++, qt

I build a project in directory A by Qt Creator, then I move the whole project folder into directory B, and use the *.pro file to open the project, but when I modify some code in the project, and found the project build and run still use the project in directory A. How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Goto Projects
2. Select Kit
3. Change Build directory

This will update `projectname.pro.user` specifically `ProjectExplorer.BuildConfiguration.BuildDirectory` key.

Comment: Or just delete .pro.user file before of launching Qt Creator

Answer (score 0):

This will help!

1. Select "Projects"
2. Under "General", uncheck "Shadow build" to use current directory.